# Получить время с сервера времени с помощью JS (десктопное приложение nw.js) для проверки подлинности

Tags: javascript, jquery, время, timestamp, nw.js

Так уж случилось, что я написал годное приложение на **nw.js** и теперь требуется его защитить с каким-либо способом. Наилучшим образом я придумал лишь способ получения **точной даты и времени** с **серверов** времени и сверки данных с вшитым ограничением.

Как получить значение даты и времени с серверов времени при помощью **JS**, с учетом что эта программа-nw.js?

p.s. ajax не изучал, не шарю и получение локального времени .Date() не рассматриваю - часы можно перевести и обмануть.

Comment: ну тут самый банальный вариант делаеш на сервер метод который будет возвращать дату к примеру  public DateTime ChekcTime() { return DateTime.Now }  и все к примеру полынй варинт  дата  + время чтоыб до секунды точно сть была  у тебя если есть свой сервер конечно но если даже не ту сделать не беда

Comment: сорян но как ты сдела годное приложение на nw.js где основа основ js  и не понимаеш асинхроных запросов

Comment: Таки придётся изучить ajax

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntp-client